# Android , Widget , Get all components from a widget

Tags: android, textview

I am creating a widget with a few textviews and a few image views.

And when i want to apply a font to all the text views, i need to get one by one with the ids
and set the font or color accordingly.

But how do i get all the text view components from the layout so that
i can set the color to them all by iterating through the components ?

Comment: Are you aware of possibility of setting styles to textviews? see `setTextAppearance()` method. This is if you are setting same style to all views..

Comment: @userSeven7s : If i have 5 text views and i want to set the color of the text inside the text view to red for all the text views, what i have to do is setTextColor(R.id.someTextView,Color.Red).So if i know dynamically the coponents inside the widget (5 text views), i was exploring the possibility of iterating through the 5 text views and setting the color for them as read.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
for( int i = 0; i < myLayout.getChildCount(); i++ ){
  if( myLayout.getChildAt( i ) instanceof TextView ){
    (TextView) myLayout.getChildAt( i ).setTextColor(#FF0000);
  }
}
```

with myLayout is your ViewGroup

Comment: Just curious here.  Are we certain the id's in a view will start at zero and go to count-1 with no holes?  I am thinking of the odd ball case where views are added and removed.

Comment: No the id are handled randomly by the environment!! you don't care if a view is removed or added you have always to count how many view you have by getChildCount() and after that look over the children one by one with getChildAt()

Comment: @K_Anas : The approach does not suit. i can only get the layout id from the remoteview and not a layout object